# NSView with layer is drawn over all content

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView, which I change some properties to give make it a rounded rectangle, with a gray color, and add it to my view (behind everything)

```
float gray = 60.0f/255.0f;
NSView* background = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: self.iconContainer.frame];
CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
[viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(gray, gray,gray, 1)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
[viewLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[background setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
[background setLayer:viewLayer];  

// Place view behind all other views
[self.iconContainer addSubview:background positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:nil];
```

However no matter what I try, that particular view is drawn above everything else.

Comment: You're leaking your background color. Since you Created it, you must Release it.

Comment: Thanks peter, however I am releasing it later with CGColorRelease(viewLayer.backgroundColor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, this behaviour is caused by the use of Core Animation layers on a subview, while the superview hasn't any.

**Enabling Core Animation layers on the superview** should fix the issue, as any subviews will then be drawn using Cora Animation layers, making the drawing process respect the order of subviews.

Comment: That was it exactly, thank you. Such a simple thing, wonder why it's not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been pondering about this for a while.

Comment: Even 4 and a half years later this was the solution!