# NSView ordering not maintain

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two `NSView` subclass objects. One i have already added to window content view. Other I have added as a subview below the first subview as below.

```
[window.contenView addSubview:secondSubview positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:firstView];
[secondSubView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

When I change the `secondSubview` to frame using animator, it animates above `firstSubview`.
As the `secondSUbview` lies below the `firstSubview`, should it not animate below the `firstSubview`.

Comment: what happens if you set a layer on both subviews (or the window itself)?

Comment: @BradAllred: If set layer to both view, and animate the second view which is below the first layer, you will see second view animating above the first view. This is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood the point of my comment so I'll post this here as an answer.

You need to put a layer on the **superview** doing so will put a layer on all the subviews and should fix the problem.

I even found this [other SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412224/nsview-with-layer-is-drawn-over-all-content) that verifies what I was trying to tell you.